# How to make a client system in java such that there is no need to make a server and the client can connect to an already existing domain like google

Tags: java, sockets, client, chat

I want to make a chat app in java and have done all the gui stuff and want it to be a bit different than other chat apps. I want to do this by having the clients connect to an existing domain or ip like google.com or discord.com. I want it so that if one connects to these domains all the clients can talk to each other there. For example if a person connects to google and someone around the globe does the same, they both can chat together. I have seen many tutorials but I see either only lan or server-client systems. I tried many different things but all just with either client and server like this one:

```
public class Sockets{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int portnumber = 2312;
        serverSocket = null;
        try{
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portnumber);

            acceptClients;
            } catch (IOException e){
                System.err.println("Could not listen to port number ", portnumber);
                System.exit(1);
            }
    }
    public static void acceptClients(){
        clients = new ArrayList<ClientThread>();
        while (true){
            try{
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                ClientThread client = new ClientThread(socket);
                Thread thread = new Thread(cient);
                thread.start();

            } catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println("Accept Failed on ", portnumber);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Client{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Socket socket = null;
        int PortNumber = 2312;
        try{
            socket = new Socket("localhost",PortNumber);
            
        } catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println("Fatal Connection error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class ClientThread extends Sockets implements Runnable{
    private Socket socket;
    public ClientThread(Socket socket){

        this.socket = socket;

    }
    @Override
    public void run(){


    }
}
```

Please help me.. Forgive me if I did something wrong and you may ask for more details.

Comment: You'll need to decide which service you want to use and consult the documentation for that service ([Discord Developer Documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro) or [Google Chat API](https://developers.google.com/chat)). These services don't use standard protocols, so you would need to use a different approach for each one. The documentation is also geared more toward building integrations than custom clients.

Comment: For the reasons @TimMoore indicated, google or discord might present extra difficulties. However, there are other choices. In particular there is protocol called XMPP (aka Jabber) that is used on many publicly available chat services. It is well documented and has decent open source client libraries in Java. [XMPP software](https://xmpp.org/software/). See also [IM observatory](https://www.xmpp.net/)

Comment: @TimMoore I think I was not clear as I wanted to have my clients connect to any sort of existing ip or domain as the room like even stackoverflow.com or youtube.com But I will still check them out thanks :D

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Let me check them thanks :D

Comment: I understand, but I’m afraid that won’t work. Your clients will only be able to work with servers that implement a compatible protocol.

Comment: @TimMoore Oh ok thanks I will then implement only a client server system then